# Use path with spaces in batch file using WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I have created WinSCP batch file for deleting files on remote server. It's working fine, but it's not working with folder with spaces.

For example, the below batch file is working:

```bash
cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://user:pwd@host" ^
    "cd /home/test/Desktop/india" ^
    "rm int.txt" ^
```

but the below batch file is not working

```bash
cd C:\Program Files\WinSCP
winscp.com /command ^
    "open sftp://user:pwd@host" ^
    "cd /home/test/Desktop/india & nepal" ^
    "rm int.txt" ^
```

I am not able to delete `india & nepal` folder file because of space

Can any one give a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path with spaces need to be [wrapped to double double-quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax):

```bash
    "cd ""/home/test/Desktop/india & nepal""" ^
```

See also [Why are some WinSCP scripting commands specified in a batch file not executed/failing?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_batch_file)

Comment: hi martin problem with spaces was solved by you. thank you vary much for your support.