# PowerShell "You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator" error when calling WinSCP.com

Tags: windows, powershell, ftp, sftp, winscp

I have a piece of code that puts a file into an FTP server. Looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command "open user@myFTPServer:MyPort/MyPath/ -privatekey=myprivatekey.ppk" "put myfile.txt" "exit"
```

This runs fine in the Windows command prompt, but when running the same thing in PowerShell it doesn't work and returns me the following error:

> "You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator"

I've tried a few combinations of my code but none of them worked:

1)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" -command "open user@myFTPServer:MyPort/MyPath/ -privatekey=myprivatekey.ppk" "put myfile.txt" "exit"
```

2)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" -command ""open user@myFTPServer:MyPort/MyPath/ -privatekey=myprivatekey.ppk" "put myfile.txt" "exit""
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since the path and/or filename of the winscp.com executable contains whitespace, invoke it with the `&` operator:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" /command "open user@myFTPServer:MyPort/MyPath/ -privatekey=myprivatekey.ppk" "put myfile.txt" "exit"
```

(assuming the command-line arguments to winscp.com are otherwise correct, of course)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it's working, but it won't get my ppk because it's under a path with white spaces. I tried adding "&" right after -privatekey but it doesn't work. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Victor Your question does not show any path with spaces. But this will probably help you: [Use path with spaces in batch file using WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46154795/850848)